# reading/storing from mysql using variables python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm new to using mysql and I'm trying to retrieve from my database and print it/ store in a variable. I've done this so far:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(database = 'UserInfo')

mycursor = conn.cursor()


Username = "Max"

Login = ("SELECT username, password FROM UserInfo.User "
         "WHERE username = '%s'")
mycursor.execute(Login, (Username))

print((username, password) in mycursor)

mycursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `fetchone()` or `fetchall()` to retrieve the results:

```
username = "Max"
query = """
    SELECT 
        username, password 
    FROM 
        UserInfo.User
    WHERE 
        username = %s
"""

mycursor.execute(query, (username, ))
username, password = mycursor.fetchone()  # here we can unpack the tuple returned from fetchone
```